# ¿Como hacer un bloque de comentario en sublime text 3?

Tags: visual-studio, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Pues eso quiero seleccionar un texto y hacerlo comentario con atajo de teclado

de esto

```
  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" *ngFor="let datos 
  of archivo">
```

a esto

```
 <!--<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" *ngFor="let 
 datos of archivo">-->
```

sin tener que estar abriendo y cerrando etiqueta

Comment: Saludos por favor si te sirvió pudieras marcarla como la respuesta a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola basta con que presiones la tecla Ctrl + la tecla que tiene el símbolo } una vez que ya seleccionaste el bloque de código que deseas comentar

Answer (score 3):

Para comentar segmento de código en Sublime Text 3 basta con usar las siguientes combinaciones de teclas.

### Windows/Linux

- Comentario de linea: **Ctrl + /**
- Comentario de bloque: **Ctrl + Shift + /**

### macOS

- Comentario de linea: **Cmd + /**
- Comentario de bloque: **Cmd + Alt + /**

---

Más referencias en los siguientes enlaces:

- http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html
- http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html

Answer (score 0):

En sublime text 3 no funcional las teclas para comentar y des-comentar código fácilmente.

En Stack Overflow encontré la solución:

Ir a **Preferences->Key Bindings - User** y pegar lo siguiente:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
```

Para probarlo, selecciona el texto, y presiona simultáneamente Ctrl7. Y listo, a disfrutar! La solución fue reemplazar el métodos abreviados de teclado por defecto Ctrl/. Por Ctrl7, que es la misma tecla en el teclado.